# Is it possible to force Windows 10 to accept an exact match for a custom accent color?

Tags: windows-10, colors

Is it possible to force Windows 10 to accept an exact match for a custom accent color?

Windows 10 (21H2) is converting my custom accent color `10, 36, 106` into `10, 39, 116`. When I enter my custom accent color from Personalize > Colors > Custom color, I see the warning:

> This color is not supported

I'm looking for a canonical answer, if possible. Or a solution if anyone has ever found one.

Comment: This [registry hack](https://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/true-black-accent-color-on-windows-10/)  purports to do it for the ("color not supported") black-ish hex value `#171717`  so it may also work for your `#0A246A` (`RGB:10,36,136`)

Comment: @BlindSpots Nope doesn't work. `ColorPrevelance=1` is equivalent to ticking the box `Apply accent color to Title Bars and window borders` in Color settings.

Comment: @Jeff and setting  `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\DWM\AccentColor` to  `0A246A` (or possibly `246A0A` if BGR vs. RGB) had no effect?

Comment: See the Gist for [AveYo's Pitch Black Theme](https://gist.github.com/AveYo/80fc6677b9f34939e44364880fbf3768)  You could model your own custom theme (registry mod) following the pattern used in the ~4 custom themes listed.  It also includes an example of a `solid color logon` and an [undo script](https://gist.github.com/AveYo/80fc6677b9f34939e44364880fbf3768#file-y_reset_accent_color_variables-reg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@BlindSpots comment above led me to [AveYo's Pitch Black Theme](https://gist.github.com/AveYo/80fc6677b9f34939e44364880fbf3768) which led me to investigate `AccentPalette`.

That led me to this little tool called [AccentPaletteTool](https://github.com/Raymai97/AccentPaletteTool/releases) which adjusts the following registry keys:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Accent]
"AccentPalette"= ; <- The tool adjusts this key only

[HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Accent]
"AccentPalette"= ; <- The tool does not adjust this key
```

Adjusting the color picker entry in row 2, column 2 forces Windows to accept my exact color.

I used lime green to illustrate the correct entry in my screenshot below, but it definitely accepts and properly renders my desired color `10 36 106`.

[image: Accent color picker tool]

**Edit**

The entry directly to the left of the lime-green entry controls the Start button Window logo hover color.

Can't figure out what the rest do, but I think they're related to pinned tiles on the Start Menu.

Comment: Glad to hear it.  Nice job.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple registry entries for accent color that you can try editing:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\DWM
HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Software\Microsoft\Windows\DWM
HKEY_USERS\[SID]\Software\Microsoft\Windows\DWM
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\SystemProtectedUserData\[SID]\AnyoneRead\Colors
```

`AccentColor` value is in hexadecimal `ABGR`, normally lowercase, so in your case `ff6a240a` for `10,36,136` RGB. `ff` means not transparent.

Don't check the color settings afterwards, there may be some mechanism that changes the color to some "acceptable" value. Verify it with some color picker tool.

Comment: I checked 'em all, the color is already set on every one: `ff6a240a`.

Comment: You mean they've all been set to that already and the color is wrong (please be more specific when replying)? Did you try restarting the system? Alternatively, try "Save theme" in Themes settings after making sure registry values are still the same.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.