# Is there a way to programmatically change the accent color in Windows 10, without signing out and back in to apply the change?

Tags: windows-10, automation, desktop-customization

I'd like to have the accent color automatically change at different times of day. Of course I don't want to constantly sign out and back in, so it needs to work without that. I'm willing to write batch files or C# or whatever.

As a test, I've tried changing the various accent color registry keys manually and even signing out and back in afterwards, but nothing changes. I've tried the registry keys mentioned in these posts:
[How can I programmatically change the Windows 11 color scheme?](https://superuser.com/questions/1798227/how-can-i-programmatically-change-the-windows-11-color-scheme),
[Is it possible to force Windows 10 to accept an exact match for a custom accent color?](https://superuser.com/questions/1784741/is-it-possible-to-force-windows-10-to-accept-an-exact-match-for-a-custom-accent)

But the question I think I'm asking for the first time is: is it possible to do this **without having to sign out**? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried just killing and restarting File Explorer?

Comment: @Ramhound I just tried it and the colors didn't update.

Comment: I know you can make it choose a color based on what background image you have. There are programs that you can install that will change the background image. If you get a background image that has the color you want a lot, and you program something to change the right image at specific times, you should be able to accomplish what you want. But there probably are programs that can set the color directly.